# If $\det(A)=0$, must the null space of $A$ be zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Came along this question:

> If $\det(A)=0$ for an $N\times N$-dimensional matrix $A$, the null space of $A$ is equal to zero.
>
> True or false? Why?

Thank you already!

Comment: Examples!! Pick a $2\times 2$ matrix with determinant $0$. You could even take the $0$ matrix. Find the null space, and contemplate.

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary. The condition $\det A=0$ is equivalent to $A\cdot x=0$ has a non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the matrix
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Notice that that the Null Space is two, but yet $det(A)=0$.